# Copy selected elements of object

Tags: javascript, object, copy

I would like to copy elements of object similar to Object.assign(), but with all parents.

Before:

```
const object = {
        a: 1,
        b: {
            c: 4,
            d: 5
        }
    };
```

After:

```
const newObject = {
    b: {
        c: 4,
    }
};
```

How to do it?

I tried use destructuring ES6, but only returns `{c: 4}`

Thanks for help!

Comment: How would you like to interrogate the object and what result do you expect?

Comment: I use object.select('b.c'); and I expect  {b: c: 4}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destructure and build up again:

```
const newObject = (({ a, b: {c, d}}) => ({ b: { c } }))(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var newObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
```

And then log it to the console to check its value

```
console.log(newObject);
```